# How to ignore JMX port when attempting to configure IntelliJ for remote Tomcat debugging?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'd like to create a simple debug configuration in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.3, so I can debug our webapp running on Tomcat 8.5.1 on Windows 10.  The IntelliJ IDEA [Help for 2018.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) says - "The server JMX port...  If you are not deploying anything with this run configuration, you don't need to specify this port."

I am not trying to deploy anything:

[image]

Yet, IntelliJ won't let me save the configuration, because I haven't specified a JMX port.

[image]

(I don't know how to make this work if I do specify a JMX port either.  I will look into how to get JMX set up in Tomcat, but I don't think that I should have to.  Again, I'm trying to create a really simple debugging configuration.)  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I am using an earlier version of IntelliJ and I don't even have a box for JMX port.  I would recommend just using whatever the default value is (e.g. 8008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there might be a slight bug in the `Run/Debug Configurations` window logic.  When I re-attempted editing the configuration, I removed the artifact to be deployed first from the `Deployment` tab.  When I did so, the window pane for the JMX configuration disappeared from the `Server` tab, and I could save the configuration.

If I re-attempted to edit the configuration by first removing the JMX port number, and then removing the artifact, I ended up with the situation described in the question, and was unable to save my edits.